# when modification of the assigned variable will affect the value of original variable?

Tags: python

```
>>> x = 10
>>> y = x
>>> y = 100
>>> y # Changes on y will not be transferred to x
100
>>> x
10

>>> x2 = 'hello'
>>> y2 = x2
>>> y2 = 'world'  # Changes on y2 will not be transferred to x2
>>> y2
'world'
>>> x2
'hello'    

>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = a
>>> b.append(3) # Changes on b will be transferred to a
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]

>>> x1 = {}
>>> y1 = x1
>>> y1['h'] = 'hhh'  # Changes on y1 will be transferred to x1
>>> y1
{'h': 'hhh'}
>>> x1
{'h': 'hhh'}
```

Question> In which cases, the value of the assigned variables will affect the value
of original variables?

Python version:　Python 3.1.2

Comment: Are you trying to discover what types are mutable?  And what types are immutable?  You should try looking for "mutable types" and read about `list` and `dict`, which are mutable.  Integers, strings (and tuples) are immutable.  You didn't try sets (mutable) or frozensets (immutable).  The documentation for mutable vs. immutable is pretty clear.  It would help us if you could reference the parts of the documentation which confused you.  What part of this was confusing?  http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider that all variables in python are indeed pointers to objects.

### Case 1

When you write

```
x = 10
```

the variable `x` is a pointer to a number object with value `10`.

```
y = x
```

the variable `y` is a pointer to the same object currently pointed by `x`.

```
y = 100
```

now the variable `y` is instead pointing to another number object with value `100`. This clearly has no effect on the object that `x` is pointing to.

### Case 2

When you write

```
x = [1, 2]
```

`x` is pointing to an array object that contains two pointers to number objects with value `1` and `2`.

```
y = x
```

`y` is now pointing to the same array as `x`

```
y.append(3)
```

this doesn't affect the variable `y` (this is the key point!), but alter the object it is pointing to (the array) by adding another element. Because `x` is also pointing to the same object the change will be visible from `x` too.

Comment: The information here is essentially correct but the terminology is non-standard. Pointers is a term not used to describe Python names. Nor is variables.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the "name" idea doesn't cover all use cases (e.g. the slot of an array or the value part of a dictionary cell). I personally never found that "name sticker" explanation really meaningful (but I'm a bottom-up guy, may be it makes sense for the top-down type).

Answer (score 3):

- In some cases you are then rebinding one of the names, but not the other, so they now are bound to different objects.

  ```
  y = 100      # Rebind y. Doesn't change x.
  y2 = 'world' # Rebind y2. Doesn't change x2.
  ```
- In other cases you are mutating the object. Then both names see the changes to the object.

  ```
  b.append(3)      # Mutates the list that both a and b are bound to.
  y1['h'] = 'hhh'  # Mutates the dictionary that both x1 and y1 are bound to.
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing values of a variable when you write `y = x`. You are binding an object to a name.

In your example

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = a
```

You have one object (a list) with two names bound to that object. Naturally, mutating changes on that object are reflected when the same object is accessed by each different name.

In your example

```
>>> x = 10
>>> y = x
>>> y = 100
```

You have 2 objects in play, integers with values `10` and `100`. When you write `y = 100` you are simply re-binding the name `y` to the other object. The name `x` is still bound to `10`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the thing: you **can't** actually really modify a variable in Python. Variables are just names for **values**. You can modify certain types of value, and you can "assign to" variables, which actually just causes them to refer to (i.e. name) some different value from what it did before.

Integer and string values cannot be modified. Lists and dictionaries can. Writing code like `b.append(3)` (where `a` and `b` initially refer to some list value) causes the name `b` to be used to look up the list **value**, which is then modified (its `.append` method is called, which causes the change). Since `a` and `b` both refer to the same value, the change is "seen by" `a`. Writing code like `b = a + [3]` creates a new value with the concatenated list, and causes `b` to refer to this new value instead of the old one. The value referred to by `a` is unaffected, in the same way that if you calculate 2 + 3 = 5, 2 is still the same 2 that it was before you did the calculation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know python much but I would assume if the value is a primitve type the original variable it not affected. Otherwise the value is only a reference which will change the original variable.